# Paint.net Alternative for macOS

Tags: image-processing, image-editor, macos

When I used windows, I used [paint.net](https://getpaint.net) and loved it.  I used it all the time.  I switched to a Mac and was disappointed when I found out there is no paint.net for Mac.  Has anyone found any good alternatives?  I've tried Pinta, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.  And GIMP looks scary ;).
Also, if you have a way to run paint.net on macOS I would love to hear how.

Comment: Can you better describe the features you are looking for?  If it is digital painting, you might want to look at Keira. https://krita.org/en/

Comment: I'm looking for something to make graphical design, but not with a Wacom tablet.  The tools I need most are Lasso, Magic Select, Shape, Layers, Mirror Image, Rotate Image, etc.  Not something too complex, but also not too simple.

Comment: Krita has those tools. You don’t have to use a pen. However there are pretty cheap pressure sensitive pens available and most should work find with Krita.

Comment: Great!  I'll give it a try and if it's what I'm looking for, I'll mark your answer as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you are a digital artist, I can suggest [Krita](https://krita.org/en/). It's really nice for painting and supports all sorts of pressure sensitive pens but you can just use a mouse or trackpad.  I've had a crash or two so I save frequently, but otherwise very well featured. Krita is open source and multi-platform.

If you are using the program for digital photography, then Apple's Photos program is actually pretty good.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!!!  Thank you!  I can even set up my keyboard shortcuts!

Comment: @Salocor Thanks. Krita isn't as lightweight as Paint.net, but it is very capable. It even has some vector tools which is great for illustrations.

Answer (score 1):

For me, feature-wise, gimp is the best replacement for paint.net.
I have use [Pinta](https://www.pinta-project.com/) by the past but I think it is closer to the base paint than paint.net

Comment: Yeah I agree.  Pinta is just lacking in features.